# How to make a class implement a call signature in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have defined the following interface in typescript:

```
interface MyInterface {
    () : string;
}
```

This interface simply introduces a call signature that takes no parameters and returns a string. How do I implement this type in a class? I have tried the following:

```
class MyType implements MyInterface {
    function () : string {
        return "Hello World.";
    }
}
```

The compiler keeps telling me that

> Class 'MyType' declares interface 'MyInterface' but does not implement it: Type 'MyInterface' requires a call signature, but Type 'MyType' lacks one

How can I implement the call signature?

Comment: For what it's worth, I [filed an issue related to this](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/154).

Comment: In this case MyInterface is acting a bit like typedef: it defines a function that is always returning string. This is a type that is subtype of function and can be used to assign type to anything that is a function, take no params and return string. A new type. Classes produce in JS the classic pattern and calling them produces Object, so a class cannot implement this interface. Basically only functions can when they are not called as constructors (i.e. with new).

Comment: There is similar question with the solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136892/overload-implementation/13140935#13140935

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Classes can't match that interface. The closest you can get, I think is this class, which will generate code that functionally matches the interface (but not according to the compiler).

```
class MyType implements MyInterface {
  constructor {
    return "Hello";
  }
}
alert(MyType());
```

This will generate working code, but the compiler will complain that `MyType` is not callable because it has the signature `new() = 'string'` (even though if you call it with `new`, it will return an object).

To create something that actally matches the interface without the compiler complaining, you'll have to do something like this:

```
var MyType = (() : MyInterface => {
  return function() { 
    return "Hello"; 
  }
})();
alert(MyType());
```

Comment: Why not `var MyType : MyInterface = function() { return "hello";};` then? I think OP's interface actually says that the implementer should be a function.

Comment: @kahoon I assumed that OP was wanting the implementor to be a function returning a string.

Comment: @PeterOlson So what's the point in having ``CallSignatures`` in interface definitions at all?

Comment: @valentin you can have an interface for more than just classes

Comment: @Valentin the main purpose of having call signatures in interface definitions is so that you can interoperate with existing javascript code.

Comment: Actually you don't neet to create such complex declaration :-) I mean that nested anonymous function is not necessary in that case.

Comment: what about method - can it implement an call signature interface?

Comment: Hi @PeterOlson! Is there a way to do the same trick with Intl.DateTimeFormat? I'm trying to extend it in order to fix zone-related problems and pass my class to material-ui DatePicker property DateTimeFormat, but the compiler says my class doesn't have the constructor-like signature. Please see https://pastebin.com/m0PBKUtg

Comment: The problem seems kinda solved this way: export default <typeof Intl.DateTimeFormat> <any> FixedIntlDateTimeFormat; Although I cannot test yet if it really works, because I haven't finished converting whole my project to TypeScript.

Answer (score 19):

In case if callable interface should have other methods you can do it like this:

```
interface Greeter {
    (): void;
    setName(name: string): void;
}

class ConsoleGreeter {

    private constructor( // constructable via `create()`
        private name = 'world'
    ) {}

    public call(): void {
        console.log(`Hello ${this.name}!`);
    }

    public setName(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static create(): Greeter {
        const instance = new ConsoleGreeter();
        return Object.assign(
            () => instance.call(),
            {
                setName: (name: string) => instance.setName(name)
                // ... forward other methods
            }
        );
    }
}

const greeter = ConsoleGreeter.create();
greeter(); // prints 'Hello world!'
greeter.setName('Dolly');
greeter(); // prints 'Hello Dolly!'
```

Downside: `greeter instanceof ConsoleGreeter` is `false`

Comment: Why did you decide to write all function callers in the `Object.assign` invocation? Why didn't you just write `Object.assign(instance.call, instance);`?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik I did so for simplicity of example. It is possible to introduce a generic solution which doesn't require to forward every instance method, but it will be not as simple as you propose...
1. Need to bind `call` method to an `instance`, otherwise `this` will be `undefined` when you invoke `call`.
2. `Object.assign` copies all enumerable OWN properties of a source object, but `instance` inherits all methods through a prototype chain.

Comment: Yeah I realised the same when I was trying to implement a custom angularjs `IHttpService` which also has the implicit call signature. It is interesting though that the first argument of the `Object.assign` is a function and not an object. This **almost** feels as if one would create a class (constructor function) with static members (not part of the prototype, but part of the constructor directly).

Comment: why `public call(): void {` has be public ?

Answer (score 9):

The code examples in this answer assume the following declaration:

```
var implementation: MyInterface;
```

#### Providing an implementation of a callable interface

As a follow-up to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12770145/238753), as suggested by some of its commentors, a function that matches the interface's call signature implicitly implements the interface. So you can use any matching function as an implementation.

For example:

```
implementation = () => "Hello";
```

You don't need to explicitly specify that the  function implements the interface. However, if you want to be explicit, you can use a cast:

```
implementation = <MyInterface>() => "Hello";
```

#### Providing a reusable implementation

If you want to produce a reusable implementation of the interface like you normally would with a Java or C# interface, just store the function somewhere accessible to its consumers.

For example:

```
function Greet() {
    return "Hello";
}

implementation = Greet;
```

#### Providing a parameterised implementation

You may want to be able to parameterise the implementation in the same way that you might parameterise a class. Here's one way to do this:

```
function MakeGreeter(greeting: string) {
    return () => greeting;
}

implementation = MakeGreeter("Hello");
```

If you want the result to be typed as the interface, just explicitly set the return type or cast the value being returned.