# Overload implementation

Tags: typescript

In the video I've found that interfaces can use strange overload technique. The code below is compiled but does not work.
I have some questions, all of them are placed inside of the code:

```
interface X{

// how can the class implements such overload ?
    f:{ 
        (s:string):string;
        (s:number):string;
        data:any;
    };
}

class xxx
{

// how to initialize this structure ?
    f:{   
        (s:string):string;
        (s:number):string;
        data:any;
    };
}


var x = new xxx();

// how should the class xxxx look to be used with this function ?
function a(x:X):string{
    return x.f("1");    
}

a(x);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I've found is to use type cast. It works, but looks quite ugly. To me this is an error in the compiler or there should be different way to do this.

UPD: Indeed, this is the only solution, http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/401235

```
interface X{
    f:{ 
        (s:string):string; 
        (s:number):string; 
        data:any; 
    };
}

class xxx
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.f = <{ (s:string):string; (s:number):string; data:any; }> function (s:any):string {return s.toString();};
        this.f.data = "data" 
    };

    f:{ 
        (s:string):string;
        (s:number):string;
        data:any;
    };
}


var x = new xxx();

function a(x:X):string{
    return  x.f("1") + x.f(1) + x.f.data;     
}

alert(a(x));
```

Comment: Downvoters: can you explain why this is a bad solution?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're trying to call the function `f` with either a string or a number.

In your interface, you define the overloads like this:

```
interface X{
    b(s:string) : string;

    f (s:string):string;
    f (s:number):string;
}
```

And you implement the interface like this.

```
class xxx implements X
{
    b(s:string) : string
    {
        return "";      
    }

    f (s: string): string;
    f (s: number) : string;
    f (s: any) : string {
        return s.toString();
    }
}
```

Here is complete example you can paste into the [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/) to try:

```
interface X {
    b(s:string) : string;
    f (s:string):string;
    f (s:number):string;
}

class xxx implements X {
    b(s:string) : string {
        return "";      
    }

    f (s: string): string;
    f (s: number) : string;
    f (s: any) : string {
        return s.toString();
    }
}

var x = new xxx();

alert(x.f("1"));
alert(x.f(5));
```

Comment: No, I'd like to know how to use the interface from my post, not yours.

Comment: Updated based on your comment.

Comment: You still have different declaration of the interface.

Comment: Yes - because you can't access the functions unless they have a key.

Comment: FTR: Reverted to original answer, which is the readable way to define overloads in TypeScript. Additionally, I would define data separately to the function overload in a class field.

Comment: You did skip the most important thing - field data as method's property. I know full well how to make override.

Comment: Well, I covered that in my previous comment. This answer is for people who encounter the question and want to use overloads. Your answer is for your localised scenario. Everyone is a winner.