# Typescript Empty Brackets Interface

Tags: typescript, wijmo

I am new to typescript, I am using the Wijimo Library and I am trying to implement the following interface

```
interface IItemCreator<T = any> {
  (): T;
}
```

I have tried the following

```
export class SystemPageModel implements wijmo.collections.IItemCreator<SystemPageModel> {

    constructor(): SystemPageModel {
        return new SystemPageModel();
    }

    public PK: Guid;
    public Name: string;
    public SystemName: string;
    public SystemTypePK: string;    

    public ff(): SystemPageModel { };
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769636/how-to-make-a-class-implement-a-call-signature-in-typescript

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all: you can't implement this interface in a class. It's a function interface.

Also, you shouldn't write `return new SameClass()` in a constructor as this will result in an endless loop.

An example to implement this would be:

```js
export class SystemPageModel {
    constructor() {
    }

    public PK: Guid;
    public Name: string;
    public SystemName: string;
    public SystemTypePK: string;
}


// ....


const systemPageModelCreator: IItemCreator<SystemPageModel> = (): SystemPageModel => {
    return new SystemPageModel();
};
```